# Rails website still at "Welcome aboard" where I expect to see content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build Rails blogger site following a [tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html), but I'm not seeing the expected web page. I've done the following:

1) I've modified the config/routes.rb file to look as follows:

```
Blogger::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :articles
end
```

2)  In db/migrate, there is a "_create_articles.rb" which I've modified to the following:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
            t.string :title
            t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In the console, I've defined several instances of the "Article" class, assigned "title" and "body" attributes, and saved them, which I confirmed by calling "Article.all" in the console:

```
irb(main):001:0> Article.all
  Article Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Article id: 1, title: "Sample Article Title", body: "This is the text for my article, woo hoo!", created_at: "2016-06-17 18:18:33", updated_at: "2016-06-17 18:18:33">, #<Article id: 2, title: "This is the second sample article", body: "Text for the second sample article", created_at: "2016-06-17 18:19:35", updated_at: "2016-06-17 18:19:35">, #<Article id: 3, title: "Third article!", body: "Lorem ipsum", created_at: "2016-06-17 18:20:01", updated_at: "2016-06-17 18:20:01">]>
```

I've also started the Rails server using the "rails server" command in project directory. However, if I go to localhost:3000 I still see the "Welcome aboard" screen (shown below), whereas I would expect at this point to see an error message "Unknown action - The action 'index' could not be found for ArticlesController".

In fact, I have been at this point before in the tutorial, but I've since closed everything and reopened it, and now I no longer see the website I expect, or any error message. Any ideas what could be amiss?

[image]

Comment: could you add your `routes.rb` file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set a root page in your `routes.rb` file to get rid of that page in development environment.

```
Blogger::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :articles
    root 'articles#index'
end
```

Comment: Thanks Uzbekjon, I now see the expected error message "Unknown action - The action 'index' could not be found for ArticlesController" and can resume the tutorial.